# Error: not all control paths return a value

Tags: c++, return-value

I am writing two functions in a program to check if a string has an assigned numeric code to its structure array or if the given numeric code has an assigned string in the same structure array. Basically, if I only know one of the two, I can get the other. I wrote the following:

```
int PrimaryIndex::check_title_pos(std::string title) {
    bool findPos = true;
    if (findPos) {
        for (int s = 1; s <= 25; s++) {
            if (my_list[s].title == title) {
                return s;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

std::string PrimaryIndex::check_title_at_pos(int pos) {
    bool findTitle = true;
    if (findTitle) {
        for (int p = 1; p <= 25; p++) {
            if (my_list[p].tag == pos) {
                return my_list[p].title;
            }
        }
    } else {
        return "No title retrievable from " + pos;
    }
}
```

However, it says not all control paths have a return value. I thought the else {} statement would handle that but it's not. Likewise, I added default "return -1;" and "return "";" to the appropriate functions handling int and string, respectively. That just caused it to error out.

Any idea on how I can keep this code, as I'd like to think it works but cant test it, while giving my compiler happiness? I realize through other searches that it sees conditions that could otherwise end in no returning values but theoretically, if I am right, it should work fine. :|

Thanks

Comment: Oh ,and I added the return -1; and return ""; to the end of each function so it would be seen as a finality, like return 0; pops up in int main()'s

Comment: Take a look at what happens if your `for` loop runs all the way to 25 without the `if` statement inside it ever being true.

Answer (score 7):

In the below snippet, if `s` iterates to 26 without the inner `if` ever evaluating to `true` then a `return` statement is never reached.

```
if (findPos) {
    for (int s = 1; s <= 25; s++) {
        if (my_list[s].title == title) {
            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought <= 25 would have it only reach 25. Should I modify s++ to ++s? The struct array goes to 25 total entries.

Comment: @Greg when s gets to 26 the loop body isn't run.

Comment: Array indices start at 0, so the valid indices for an array with 25 items  are 0 to 24.

Comment: @Greg it may be simpler to remove your `else` entirely, as the failure return 'appears' to be what you want when it falls through, although I'm having trouble understanding the exact logic behind `findPos` which is always set to true.

Comment: no no. I need it true, to begin with to take the loop in to account. I imagine there is a more creative way to run this. Anyhow, I get what you guys are saying I just have figured out the best way for me to achieve this yet. I took off the = on <=25 so that it would stop. I'm tinkering

Comment: I'm just trying to think of a case where the `else` would be followed.

Comment: @Greg Loops (and ending conditions) are evaluated at run time. A static code analysis tool might have told you clearer what you've been missing there.

Comment: Thank you @ polarysekt. That worked. I know the other guys said something that probably should have assisted, and I appreciate your knowledge on that one @ πάντα ῥεῖ I will remember that in the future.